# Interactive q/kdb Build System to Sublime 3

Tags: cmd, sublimetext3, kdb, sublime-text-plugin, sublime-syntax

I'm trying to enable the interactive kdb/q run mode in Sublime text. Standalone I'm able to run any q script inside ST but interactive mode is not working.

Below is my code.

Build file:

```
{ 
   "cmd": ["X:/path/path/q", "-u", "$file"],
   "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
   "selector": "source.q"
}
```

repl file:

```
{
   "target": "run_existing_window_command",
   "id": "repl_q_run",
   "file": "config/q/Main.sublime-menu"
}
```

added "-i" for interactive run in "Main.sublime-menu" (repl_q_run sub program) like below.

```
"cmd": ["X:/path/path/q",   "-u","-i", "-m", "pdb", "$file_basename"],
```

> Error:  '2017.08.11T17:15:34.847 -i. OS reports: The system cannot
>   find the file specified. 0: ("S*";":") `-i
>
> ***Repl Closed***

Thank you,
Vanditha

Answer (score 0):

`-i` is not a valid command line option for `q`.  For the list of valid options, see the [reference card](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/card/#command-line-options-and-system-commands).

The options you are using, `-u`, `-i` and `-m pdb` look like python options.  Please note that unlike python, `q` expects command line options to be specified after the script.